# Why the styles are not being applied to the wordpress custom theme?

Tags: wordpress

I have downloaded a template from the w3layouts. I want this template to be shown as a wordpress theme. I have converted index.html to index.php and the style.css and index.php are both in the same directory, I have also used bloginfo() function of php. Here is the head section of my index.php

```
<link rel="icon" href="<?php bloginfo('img/favicon.png')?>" />
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('bootstrap.min.css')?>" />
    <!-- animate CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('animate.css')?>" />
    <!-- owl carousel CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('owl.carousel.min.css')?>" />
    <!-- themify CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('themify-icons.css')?>" />
    <!-- flaticon CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('flaticon.css')?>" />
    <!-- font awesome CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('magnific-popup.css')?>" />
    <!-- swiper CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('slick.css')?>" />
    <!-- style CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('style.css')?>" />
```

I have put the folder of my template in themes folder of wordpress. index.php and style.css both are in css folder. I am a newbie to wordpress. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your functions.php file add this: 
/resources/css/ is the path to your styles.

```
define( 'THEME_DIR', get_template_directory_uri() )

wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style-css', THEME_DIR . '/resources/css/style.css' );
```

Later in the head tag of your HTML template add

```
<head>
// ... ...
wp_head();

</head>
```

Comment: I do not have a functions.php file. What is it? and where is it supposed to be?